# Variable value passing eeror in openERP

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I have a model named `hr_bank_account` (`osv.osv`) and it looks like this:

```
 class hr_bank_account(osv.osv):

    def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
        vals = {}
        acc_no = 'account_no'
        bank = self.pool.get('hr.bank.register').browse(cr, uid, values['bank_id']).name
        branch = self.pool.get('hr.branch.registration').browse(cr, uid, values['branch_id']).name
       # name = str(bank) + '/' + str(branch) + '/' + str(values['account_no'])
       # get 'account_no' and replace it with acc_no bellow. 
        name = str(bank) + '/' + str(branch) + '/' + acc_no
        values.update({'name': name})
        return super(hr_bank_account, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)


    _name = "hr.bank.account"
    _description = "hr_bank_account"
    _columns = {
                'name': fields.char('Account No', size=256),
                'bank_id': fields.many2one('hr.bank.register', 'Bank Name',),
                'branch_id': fields.many2one('hr.branch.registration','Branch Name',domain="[('bank_id','=',bank_id)]"),
                'account_no': fields.integer('account_no', size=64, required=True),
    }

hr_bank_account()
```

I have a table named `hr_employee` and it has the following relationship:

```
'bank_account_id': fields.one2many('hr.bank.account', 'account_no', 'Bank account'),
```

My issue is that when it is given a bank account number, it passes wrong values like below:

The number I give as the bank account number = 123456

The number which goes to the database is = account_no

Please help me to fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace **create** method with ->

```
    def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
    vals = {}
    for item in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        acc_no = str(item.name)
    bank = self.pool.get('hr.bank.register').browse(cr, uid, values['bank_id']).name
    branch = self.pool.get('hr.branch.registration').browse(cr, uid, values['branch_id']).name
   # name = str(bank) + '/' + str(branch) + '/' + str(values['account_no'])
   # get 'account_no' and replace it with acc_no bellow. 
    name = str(bank) + '/' + str(branch) + '/' + acc_no
    values.update({'name': name})
    return super(hr_bank_account, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your create method:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
    # Check all values are in values or not
    if values.get('account_no','') and values.get('bank_id','') and values.get('branch_id',''):
        acc_no = values.get('account_no','')
        bank = self.pool.get('hr.bank.register').browse(cr, uid, values.get('bank_id','')).name
        branch = self.pool.get('hr.branch.registration').browse(cr, uid, values.get('branch_id','')).name
        # Concate  all fields 
        name = str(bank) + '/' + str(branch) + '/' + acc_no
        values.update({'name': name})
    return super(hr_bank_account, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```